# Call to a member function fetch() on array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Я новичок, подскажите пожайлуйста - в чем тут ошибка?

```
public static function getAdminEmails()
{

    // Запрос к БД
    $result = DB::select('select * from admin_emails');
    print_r($result);
    $i = 0;
    $email = array();
    while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
        $email[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
        $email[$i]['name'] = $row['name'];
        $email[$i]['value'] = $row['value'];
        $email[$i]['created_at'] = $row['created_at'];
        $email[$i]['updated_at'] = $row['updated_at'];
        $i++;
    }
    return $email;
}
```

Comment: "Я новичок" - это не повод не читать документацию и не смотреть примеры

Comment: и не читать сообщения об ошибке, если уж на то пошло

Comment: зачем вообще этот код, если тебе пишет что  $array - это *уже массив*?

Comment: @Ипатьев а как мне нужно в массив $email занести данные из таблиц?

Comment: Я попробую еще раз. зачем что-то куда-то заносить, если тебе пишет что $result - это уже массив?

Comment: @Ипатьев

тогда вызов в контроллере - public function index()
    {

        $email = AdminEmail::getAdminEmails();
        $promoCode = PromoCode::getPromoCode();
        //    Return view HomePage
        return view('pages/home', $email['value'], $promoCode['value'] );

    }

Comment: что такое $email['value']? я бы предложил отложить на время laravel и попробовать освоить язык РНР. чтобы было хотя бы минимальное понимание своих действий.